# Sending POST request to a webservice from python

Tags: python, web-services, rest

I'm trying to send a POST request to a restful webservice. I need to pass some `json` in the request.It works with the curl command below

```
curl --basic -i --data '<json data string here>' -H Content-type:"text/plain" -X POST http://www.test.com/api
```

I need some help in making the above request from Python. To send this POST request from python I have the following code so far:

```
import urllib
url='http://www.test.com/api'
params = urllib.urlencode... #What should be here ?
data = urllib.urlopen(url, params).read()
```

I have the following three questions:

1. Is this the correct way to send the resuest ?.
2. How should i specify the params value ?
3. Does content-type need to be specified ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `httplib` has an [example](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib-examples) of sending a post request.

```
>>> import httplib, urllib
>>> params = urllib.urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue', '@action': 'show'})
>>> headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
...            "Accept": "text/plain"}
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("bugs.python.org")
>>> conn.request("POST", "", params, headers)
>>> response = conn.getresponse()
>>> print response.status, response.reason
302 Found
>>> data = response.read()
>>> data
'Redirecting to <a href="http://bugs.python.org/issue12524">http://bugs.python.org/issue12524</a>'
>>> conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Construct a `dict` of the data you want to be sent as a POST request.
2. [`urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) the dict to get a string.
3. [`urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) the URL you want, passing in the optional `data` parameter as your encoded POST data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have the dict of the data. Can u please give an example for the next step, i.e. urlencode ?

Comment: @Joe: you call the function `urlencode` and pass it the dict of the data as an argument! How hard can it be?

Answer (score 1):

the question deals with sending the parameters as "json"..
you need to set the Content-Type to application/json in the headers and then send the paramters without urlencoding..

ex:

```
url = "someUrl"

data = { "data":"ur data"}


header = {"Content-Type":"application/json","User-Agent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)"}

#lets use httplib2

import httplib2 
http = httplib2.Http()

response, send = http.request(url,"POST",headers=header,body=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `urllib.urlencode()` if `Content-Type` is not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
import json, urllib2

data = {"some": "json", "d": ["a", "ta"]}
req = urllib2.Request("http://www.test.com/api", data=json.dumps(data),
                      headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
print urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

endpoint = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
data = '{ id: 1 }'

result = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, data=data)
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a sample snippet on POST request of json. The results will be printed in your terminal.

```
import urllib, urllib2

url = 'http://www.test.com/api'
values = dict(data=json.dumps({"jsonkey2": "jsonvalue2", "jsonkey2": "jsonvalue2"}))
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
rsp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = rsp.read()

print content
```